# How do I fix "System.MissingMethodException = {"Can't find PInvoke DLL 'user32.dll'."} on Windows 6.5?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile-6.5

I am trying to use pInvoke, but on both the emulator and on the device the invoke fails.  I am new to .NET (Am a C++ developer) and I don't understand how the JIT/framework can't find that DLL/method/etc.

Is there something else I have to do to get it to work?

In looking at similar questions it appears that I may or may not have to add the DLL to either the solution or the CAB - but where do I get that file.

Surely the OS on the device has user32.dll?  And the Windows 7 version cannot possibly be the correct one to install on the device, can it?

EDIT

Any one of these fails:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "SipShowIM")]
        public static extern bool SipShowIMP(int code);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

Comment: Could you provide the PInovke signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Surely the OS on the device has user32.dll?

No, unfortunately it doesn't.  Windows Mobile doesn't include `user32.dll`, as well as many other normal Windows API DLLs.  Instead, you typically need to P/Invoke into `coredll.dll` instead.  For signatures, see [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/CreateProcess.html#)'s section (at the bottom left) for "Smart Device Functions".

---

Edit:

Some of the signatures on there are obviously incorrect, as you mention in the comments.  You can look at the Windows Mobile API for the functions (such as [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931583.aspx)) to get the correct signature.

I believe, for yours, most should be in `coredll.dll`:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "SipShowIM")]
public static extern bool SipShowIMP(int code);

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

Comment: So then where do I get them from?

Comment: I did look at that link you provided - but the signatures still show user32.dll.  I am confused.  - http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.SetWindowPos#

Comment: I just changed the name from user32 to coredll and it seems to work.  thanks